# PHP call to shell script to handle multiple users

Tags: php, shell, multiple-instances

I have a C simulation for which I'm creating a graphical web interface. I used HTML with ajax to call PHP, which in turn calls the shell to run the simulation. The output is then passed back to the webpage.

The script generates an output file (with a link outputted to the webpage) as well as a graph (using a call to gnu plot and referencing the output file). The webpage also allows the user to upload an input file which is used in the C simulation. All of these files are user specific.

If there is only one user on the webpage at a time, there isn't any problem. However, if 5 people want to run the simulation at the same time, the user-specific files (output, graph, input) would all be getting overwritten and messed up.

I don't have any MySQL experience, and I also don't plan on saving the outputs or inputs for a given user (user can download them if he/she wishes), so I was hoping there might be a rather simple solution like, for example, generating a temporary directory on the server with some sort of identifying tag in the name based on the user's IP address or something. This folder could then be removed some number of minutes after the simulation runs. Anyone have any ideas about something like that?

Or will I have to resort to MySQL?

Edit: It would also be okay to have something like allowing a maximum of 5 users running at the same time and then create a queue for additional users, but that might be even more difficult.

Thanks,
Josh

Comment: if you send a link to the output back to the user, shouldn't the output exist for longer then a couple of minutes?

Comment: perhaps. the output consists of a number (the result of a 3-D numerical integral), a file that contains a distribution (smaller ranges within the integral range), and a graph. The output is only really useful in downloaded format, so I was thinking the user would either grab it or not want it. But "a few minutes" was just an example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do it without saving the output *somewhere*, so your temp dir plan is fine.

- Assign each new user a unique id, via md5() or sha1() or whatever.
- Pass the id to the simulator and have it create its output files in a subdirectory named by that id.
- Render the links and image HREFs according to that id..
- Write a cron to periodically purge the stale subdirs.

Each person will get their own output set, on an unguessable URL.

Comment: This is exactly what I had in mind, even up to using a cron to purge the directories. I just wanted to make sure I was on the right path. I also didn't really know much about session ids, so md5() and sha1() were great places to start my google searching.

Comment: Heh well, I wouldn't say it's the "right" path, just one of many possible.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you could use [Threading](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mY__o6mq0uI) in your C simulation. Alternatively, you could set up a MySQL database and store the data there using [PHP Database Objects (PDO)](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php). If you can use C and are able to do ajax with PHP, mysql will probably the most time efficient solution to implement as opposed to threading in C (assuming the C simulation is relatively complex)

Answer (score 1):

You can create a session identifier for a visiting user and pass that id as a parameter to your c program.

When your c program creates files for user to display it should generate name using your session identifier for that user.

From web page let users to view files that match their session identifier. This way they can see files they generated and also you can put a control for users if they have a file with their session identifier you don't need to do an unnecessary call to your c program.

Just serve the one which was already created. Control life time of that identifier as you wish.